# How to find minimum value in NSMutableArray in Objective C

Tags: math, coordinate

I have 7 float values shorted in NSMutableArray, i need to find the shortest value in between them, how do i find that shortest value

Comment: it would help if you provide some data

Comment: Hi udo i have four values like 3.2,1.5,6.7,8.5 and these values are stored in NSMutableArray, i need to find the smallest value in between them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
int k = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];
for (unsigned i = 1; i < [yourArray count]; i++){
    if([yourArray objectAtIndex:i] < k) k = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Comment: Also use integerValue to store objects